# How can I get the volume of sound of a video in Python using moviepy?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

I want to get the volume of sound of a video so I use the following:

```
import numpy as np # for numerical operations
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate

clip = VideoFileClip("soccer_game.mp4")
cut = lambda i: clip.audio.subclip(i,i+1).to_soundarray(fps=22000)
volume = lambda array: np.sqrt(((1.0*array)**2).mean())
volumes = [volume(cut(i)) for i in range(0,int(clip.audio.duration-2))]
```

But I get these errors:

```
Exception AttributeError: "VideoFileClip instance has no attribute 'reader'" in <bound method VideoFileClip.__del__ of <moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip.VideoFileClip instance at 0x084C3198>> ignored

WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

I am using IPython notebook and Python 2.7. 
I assume something doesn't have the appropriate permissions. I have changed run this program as an administrator for ffmpeg.exe, ffplay.exe, ffprobe.exe.

Comment: why are you not just using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed a bug today that may have caused your problem, would you mind upgrading and trying again ? If it still doesn't work, I'll need to know your windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing own calculations, I would recommend to use an existing library or tool that considers the [human-perceived loudness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_normalization).

For example, `ffmpeg` [can measure the loudness](https://superuser.com/questions/1424343/how-can-i-get-the-final-luf-value-with-ffmpeg) based on the [EBU R 128 recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBU_R_128) (in [LUFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LKFS)).

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260438/how-to-extract-perceived-loudness-of-a-speech-signal-in-an-audio-wav-file-usin) recommends [`pyloudnorm`](https://github.com/csteinmetz1/pyloudnorm).