# How to extract perceived loudness of a speech signal in an audio (WAV) file using Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, speech-recognition, pydub, praat

I would like to extract loudness of a speech signal from an audio file (WAV). I believe it is a perceived quantity that depends not only on the amplitude of a signal but also the frequencies involved. I found a link that was useful https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/463 but I

1. would like to use existing packages that calculate this efficiently
2. am uncertain the approach described here is appropriate.

For 1, I found [Parselmouth](https://pypi.org/project/praat-parselmouth/), a wrapper around [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) to work with, but am unsure on how to proceed after extracting the Intensity and Pitch values by doing so:

```
snd = parselmouth.Sound(path)

intensity = snd.to_intensity()
pitch = snd.to_pitch()
```

I have also looked into [Pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) and [PyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis) but couldn't find direct methods of evaluating loudness using those either.

What is a pythonic, package object-oriented way of extracting loudness from a WAV file?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pyloudnorm](https://github.com/csteinmetz1/pyloudnorm):

```
import soundfile as sf
import pyloudnorm as pyln

data, rate = sf.read("test.wav")
meter = pyln.Meter(rate) #
loudness = meter.integrated_loudness(data)
```